# Returning value from asynchronous handler to containing method

Tags: java, vert.x

Given the following two classes:

```
public class Test {

    public void call() {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        myClass.methodOne().subscribe(v -> {...});
    }
}

public class MyClass {

    public Observable<String> methodOne() {
        Observable<String> response =  Observable.fromFuture(this.methodTwo());
        return response;
    }

    public CompletableFuture<String> methodTwo() {
        CompletableFuture<String> response = new CompletableFuture<>();
        KafkaProducerRecord<String, String> record = KafkaProducerRecord.create(...);

        response.complete("initial value");

        kafkaProducer.write(record, done -> {
            if(done.succeeded()) {
                response.complete("done");
            }
            else {
                response.complete("not done");
            };
        );

        return response;
    }
}
```

Where `kafkaProducer` is an instance of `io.vertx.kafka.client.producer.impl.KafkaProducerImpl`.

The expected behavior is that when `response.complete()` has been called in `MyClass.methodTwo()`, the `response` value will be returned from `methodTwo()` to `methodOne()`. That value will then get wrapped in a future and will be available within the handler of `subscribe` in `Test.call()`.

However, because of the asynchronous processing `methodTwo()` will always return "initial value" which was set before the write method of the `vertx. kafkaProducer`.

Even though at some later point `response` will be set within the handler to either "done" or "not done" that value is never returned.

I have tried changing the code in `methodTwo` to the following:

```
AsyncResult<RecordMetadata> res = 
Single.create((SingleEmitter<AsyncResult<RecordMetadata>> emitter) ->
   producer.write(record,   result -> emitter.onSuccess(result)))
   .blockingGet();
```

with the idea of then returning the value in `AsyncResult`, but this blocks indefinitely.

What is the correct way to approach this?

Thanks

Comment: Again, how is this related to RxJava? Also calling `response.complete` a second time will have no effect. Plus, what you wanted requires blocking as Java doesn't support suspension or continuations yet.

Comment: Thanks Alfe. Is the right approach to use Vertx-Sync and wrap the call to kafkaProducer.write() in Sync.awaitResult(), or is there a better way?

Comment: I have tried using Single.create and have edited the question to show that, but that appears to just block indefinitely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Vert.x [Handler](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Handler.html) to handle the result of your async call.
Once the async call gets completed you can call the handler which got passed with the result.

A small snippet relating to address your problem is below.

```
public class Test {

    public void call() {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        myClass.methodTwo(f-> {
            if (f.succeeded()) {
                //do something with f.result()
            }
            else {
                //handle;
            }
        });
    }
}

public class MyClass {

    public void methodTwo(Handler<AsyncResult<String>> handler) {
        KafkaProducerRecord<String, String> record = KafkaProducerRecord.create(...);

        //response.complete("initial value");

        kafkaProducer.write(record, done -> {
            if(done.succeeded()) {
                handler.handle("done");
            }
            else {
                handler.handle("not done");
            };
        );

        //return response;
    }
}
```